# WPF DataGrid TargetType="DataGridRow" not working for Event="MouseDoubleClick"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to add an onclick event on the DataGrid rows but it does not work with my code. It only works when `TargetType="DataGridCell"`. This is my DataGrid;

```
<DataGrid Name="CourtCasesGrid" Grid.Column="0" BeginningEdit="dataGrid_BeginningEdit" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCourtCase}" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CourtCasesGridRowDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this over, and successfully gotten on-double-click the row selected spurring an event, similarly permitting the value of the row to be collected. I've done this using Code-Behind, but can also assist with an MVVM approach if that's useful to you.

Here's the 'MainWindow.xaml' code-behind:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public DataGridRow SelectedRow { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CourtCase> CourtCases { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CourtCases = new ObservableCollection<CourtCase>();
            CourtCases.Add(new CourtCase("1"));
            CourtCases.Add(new CourtCase("2"));
            CourtCases.Add(new CourtCase("3"));
            CourtCases.Add(new CourtCase("4"));

            SelectedRow = new DataGridRow();

            CourtCasesGrid.DataContext = CourtCases;
        }

        private void CourtCasesGridRowDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        }
    }
```

Here's the 'MainWindow.xaml' view:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CourtCases,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"  Name="CourtCasesGrid" ColumnWidth="*"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CourtCasesGridRowDoubleClick"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

And even the simple class I'm using to hold court data, for your reference:

```
 public class CourtCase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CourtCase()
    {
        Name = "";
    }
    public CourtCase(string n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!